# How to find names of columns that have non English values? R

Tags: r

I have a data as shown in image some columns have non English words how can I find those column names using R programming?

Data and expected result is shown in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c("some", "data", "ß", "کابل"),
  Var2 = c("کابل", "data", "کابل", "data"),
  Var3 = c("some", "data", "more", "data"),
  Var4 = c("some", "data", "more", "data")
)
df
```

The solution first strings all columns together using `paste0`and then deselects (`-`) those column strings in `which` `grepl`finds matches of non-ASCII characters (which are equivalent to non-English characters):

```
df[, -which(grepl("[^ -~]", apply(df, 2, paste0, collapse = " ")))]

  Var3 Var4
1 some some
2 data data
3 more more
4 data data
```

EDIT:

To get **only** the names, simply insert the whole statement into `names`:

```
names(df[, -which(grepl("[^ -~]", apply(df, 2, paste0, collapse = " ")))])
[1] "Var3" "Var4"
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Please consider ticking the arrow in the left upper corner to indicate that you've accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
lapply(df, function(x){
ifelse(grepl("\\@", x), x, gsub(paste0(c(letters, LETTERS), collapse = "|"), "", x))})
```

Return names:

```
names(df)[sapply(df, function(x) {
  ifelse(grepl("\\@", x), FALSE,
         any(gsub(paste0(
           c(letters, LETTERS), collapse = "|"
         ), "", x) == ""))
})]
```